# Prevent bash vi multiline collapse

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, vi, multiline

When doing a command line edit in Ubuntu Precise bash how do I prevent vi from converting

```
for ii in `ls -a`
do
    echo $ii
done
```

to this...

```
for ii in `ls -a`; do echo $ii; done
```

Even if I gsub the ';' for a '^M', when I :wq out of the tmp file it reverts to semicolon.

I have "set -o vi" and "EDITOR=vi" in my .bashrc file. Otherwise vanilla install.

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash vi mode, this is general bash behavior. I've added the bash tag for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the `cmdhist` and `lithist` shell options. Try the following command:

```
shopt -s lithist
```